# Google dialogflow integration - Hangout chat integration option not available

Tags: dialogflow-es, integration, chatbot, google-hangouts

I build an agent on google Dialogflow and want it to integrate with Hangout Chatbot, but the option is not present in the integrations option. Why is that so? As I have worked with my friend and in his Google Dialogflow account hangout option is available in the integration field of Dialogflow.

[Google Dialogflow Integration option screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh5Kj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you own a Google Workspace account, then you can do it, as it says the integration is only available for Google Workspace users. See https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/hangouts